# how to delay one function until another function completes?

Tags: function, meteor, delay

I am having difficulty finding the answer to this question - I suspect because I'm probably not using the right terminology. I am using Meteor.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Function A - returns the flickr userID based on userAPI and username
Function B - uses the userID generated by Function A
```

The problem I have is that `Function B` is completing before `Function A` has had a chance to retrieve the information from Flickr.

What is the best manner to delay `Function B` and somehow connect it to the successful completion of `Function A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Meteor is an async framework built on top of Node, you have to think a little differently then you're probably used to.  One way to do this would be as follows.

```
var a = function(cb){
  var flickerId = getFlickerId();

  cb(flickerId);
};

var b = function(flickerId){
  //do something with the id
};

//call it
a(b);
```

I'm guessing you're using some framework that gets the flicker info for you.  That framework probably has a function call which takes a callback like function 'a' above.

As the callback stack grows deeper and deeper this sort of code can become confusing.  Once you have mastered the above, I suggest looking into https://github.com/kriskowal/q for a cleaner solution.